# How to get the previous word with regex?

Tags: regex, cpu-word

I have a path like this one:

C:\Development.TFS\Examn\R4-branch\Web\OrganisationManager\themes\blue\css

And I need a regex to get the word "blue" out of there. I tried, but didn't find a solution yet. It's practically getting the word before the last word from that string.
Please help,
thank you

Comment: you should state the language you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(\w+)\W+\w+$
```

matches the second-to-last word, captures it into backreference no. 1, then matches one or more non-word characters, then the last word and then EOL.

If you don't really want actual words but path elements to match (even if they contain non-word characters), then

```
([^\\:]+)\\[^\\]+$
```

might do a better job.

Edit: Added a `:` to the "second-to-last-word group" so the regex can handle relative paths, too.

Comment: Path elements contains non-word characters, e.g. 'R4-branch' contains '-'. So your regex won't match 'C:\Development.TFS\Examn\R4-branch\Web\OrganisationManager\themes\blue-sea\css'

Comment: You're right of course. The OP asked for words, though, not path elements (which he probably meant). Will edit.

Comment: Yes, this is nicer! It will even correctly work with spaces unlike mine =)

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I actually wanted that path element, but your answer helped a lot :)

Comment: Right again. Well, the more specific the requirements, the better the regex.

Answer (score 1):

can't you simply split the string using the character '\' then get the splitResult[splitResult.Count-1]?

you could always replace '\' by the path separator in your environment, for more consistent results

Answer (score 0):

You should find this pattern in string: `([\w\s.-]+)\\[\w\s.-]+$`. The first group will containg word 'blue' in your case. Exact syntax of regex and accessing groups depends on your programming language.

Comment: `\d` is a subset of `\w`, so `\w\d` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

if (eregi('themes\\([a-z].+)\\css', $subject)) {
 # Successful match
} else {
 # Match attempt failed
}

A PHP example to get the word blue.

Comment: Maybe you must try regex buddy

it is a great tool to make regexes

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
(\w+)\\\w+$
```

Comment: I posted this and deleted as the "words" in OP's path can include non `\w` characters like `-`,`.`,`space` etc.